# Keras Image data augmentation

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am finding it hard to understand how **flow_from_directory** of **ImageDataGenerator** works, I am using the following code to augment image data for my CNN model, as no of training images available are very less.

```
batch_size = 16
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_transformed = 'dataset/train_transformed'
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'dataset/train',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    save_to_dir=train_transformed,
    save_prefix='train_aug',
    save_format='png')
```

Its a binary classification problem having 20 positive and 20 negative images. So i have **dataset/train** folder with 2 subfolders having 20 images each. When i train the model with above image generator, i can see **4160** images being saved in **dataset/train_transformed** folder and presuming **4160** images being used for training the model.

```
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=1000 // batch_size,
    epochs=5,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=100 // batch_size)
```

According to my understanding, 
No. of samples in each epoch = batch_size X steps_per_epoch
As my steps_per_epoch = 1000/16 = 62,
 #Samples in each epoch should be **62 x 16 = 992**

No of epochs is set to 5, so total generated images should be **992 x 5 = 4960**.

 And no of images generated are random with same hyperparameters.

 Just needed an explanation for above configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculations seem to be correct. Also be aware that `flow_from_directory` has a `shuffle` argument (true by default). This means that the generator will yield 992 images during each epoch (`batch_size` times `steps_per_epoch`), but the order in which they appear will be different for each epoch.

Comment: Even if the order in they appear is different for each epoch, finally the total images used for training should be 4960, but that is not the case.